# why it does shows up the type 'list' when i use set function in python 3 ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
a = [3.2,1,3,1,4,1,3423] 
s = sorted(set([aa for aa in a]))
print(type(s))
output - class 'list'
```

Can someone explain this!  why it does showing 'list' instead of 'set' .After i run the program without the sorted method it shows up class 'set.

Comment: Because `sorted` creates a **list** that is sorted. A set has by the way no order...

Comment: `sorted` creates a list out of the collection you give it. You can [read its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to see this.

Comment: A good habit to get into is just checking the official docs. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and idea which helped me to dig into python. @pvg and others :)

Answer (score 0):

**`sorted(..)` is a function that constructs a list**. It does not take into account the type of the "source", it takes an iterable as input and constructs a list with that input. Or as is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> Return a **new sorted list** from the items in iterable.

Since `sorted(..)` is implemented by Python itself, and does not takes advantage of some protocol of the class itself, it would even be impossible to construct a collection type that is sorted for every collection type.

Furthermore the **`set`s in Python are unodered**: if you construct a set with elements, there is no guarantee that that order will be the same as the insertion order, nor that the order will be the same when you update the set.